# Object oriented programming - Overriding a base class

Tags: python, overriding

What is method overriding? What is the exact need or use of method overriding? An example with a python code will be more useful.

Comment: This is one of the most basic OOP feature and there's more than plenty of litterature about OOP...

Comment: @user5769010 Try googling this and figuring it out for yourself - there is a _lot_ available on the internet about this. Then try implementing it yourself in Python and if you have problems then SO may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car(object):
    def shifting(self):
        return "manual"

class AutoCar(Car):
    def shifting(self):
        return "automatic"

autos = [Car(), AutoCar()]

for auto in autos:
    print(auto.shifting())
```

In this basic example `AutoCar` has overriden the method `shifting` of the base class.

Were you to receive a list with a mix of unknown `Car`s (Manual and Automatic) you can query the `shifting` method and find out.

Of course given Python is dynamically typed, the list could contain instances from other class types which also have a `shifting` method. But it's not the point.

Output:

```
manual
automatic
```